# How can I do 2 request at the same time to the server (asp.net mvc 3)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, controller, long-integer, polling

I really dont know how should I proceed to be able to poll information with a jscript and continue to call other script that will call methode on the server side.

What i want is to do stuff for 42 seconds, and then if its take too much time kill the process, otherwise return the new json data.

But the problem is that when I want to call new method while this is working, it wont let me because its simple threaded. I tried with async controller, but im not sure if I do it fine here is part of the code :

**Controller**

```
    public class CadController : AsyncController

{

    /// <summary>
    /// Use to set the view and set the model in memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="RessourceNo">The ressource number</param>
    /// <returns>The new view</returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var _model = new PollModels();
        HttpRuntime.Cache["PollModels"] = _model;
        return View(_model);
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Use to change the data of the model
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The new html code</returns>
    public void CadDataAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        CadDataService _service = new CadDataService();
        _service.GetPollModelsCompleted += (sender, e) =>
         {
             AsyncManager.Parameters["pollModels"] = e.getValue();
             AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
         };
        _service.GetPollModelsAsync();
    }

    public JsonResult CadDataCompleted(PollModels pollModels)
    {
        return Json(pollModels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    #region [Partial View]

    /// <summary>
    /// Use to set nothing for a div
    /// useful if you want to hide something when you change page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Model">A CadModels Model</param>
    /// <returns>An empty result</returns>
    public ActionResult Blank()
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Use to send the new status to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Status">The new status</param>
    /// <param name="Model">The buttons models</param> 
    /// <returns>a empty view</returns>
    public ActionResult PushButton(string description, string code)
    {
        var _manager = new GeneralManager();
        GeneralModels _generalModel = _manager.GetGeneralModels();

        AppEnt.Cad.CadResource _ress = AppBus.Cad.CadResource.GetCadResourceFromName(_generalModel.RessourceNo);
        _ress.ResourceStatusDesc = description;
        _ress.ResourceStatusCode = code;
        ServerV5.GetInstance().Update(_ress);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

**CadDataService**

```
    public class CadDataService
{

    int getSleep() { return (int)SH.eServiceTime.eCadData; }
    void DoSleep() { Thread.Sleep(getSleep()); }

    public PollModels GetPollModels()
    {
        DoSleep();
        var manager = new LongPollingManager();
        return manager.GetPollModels();
    }

    public event EventHandler<PollModelEventArgs> GetPollModelsCompleted;


    public void GetPollModelsAsync()
    {
        SynchronizationContext syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Timer timer = new Timer(state =>
            syncContext.Send(d => OnGetPollModelsCompleted(new PollModelEventArgs()), state),
            null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
        HttpContext.Current.Items[this] = timer; // don't let the GC kill the timer
    }

    private void OnGetPollModelsCompleted(PollModelEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<PollModelEventArgs> handler = GetPollModelsCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

}

**And finnaly the EventArgs**

```
    public class PollModelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public PollModels Value;
    public PollModelEventArgs()
    {

    }

    public PollModels getValue()
    {
        var _manager = new LongPollingManager();
        Value = _manager.GetPollModels();
        return Value;
    }


}

public static class SH
{
    public enum eServiceTime { eCadData = 700, };
}
```

Comment: nevermind i found what I needed ( http://tech-journals.com/jonow/2011/10/22/the-downsides-of-asp-net-session-state)